# Whats the difference between indexed retrieval and keyed retrieval

Tags: c#, list, collections, complexity-theory

Looking at the docs for `KeyedCollection` i read the following::

> The KeyedCollection class provides both O(1) indexed retrieval and keyed retrieval that approaches O(1).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.keyedcollection-2?view=netcore-3.1

I do not fully understand what this means. I personally would think that indexed retrieval and keyed retrieval are the same since a dictionary indexes by keys. I feel a bit vague about the terms 'indexed retrieval' and 'keyed retrieval' altogether i suppose.

So what's the difference, and why is the complexion different?

Additional info:
I personally would like to use the `keyedCollection` because I have a list that will be added to a lot. Now and then i need to fetch an item by an id - a `Guid` and return some data. I also periodically will  go through the list and delete any items i no longer use.

Sample;

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A collection of leases. Implements <see cref="KeyedCollection{TKey,TItem}"/> which is a dictionary-list hybrid.
    /// </summary>
    public class LeaseInfoCollection : KeyedCollection<Guid, LeaseInfo>
    {
        #region Construction and Destruction

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public LeaseInfoCollection()
        {
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public LeaseInfoCollection(IEqualityComparer<Guid> comparer)
            : base(comparer)
        {
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public LeaseInfoCollection(IEqualityComparer<Guid> comparer, int dictionaryCreationThreshold)
            : base(comparer, dictionaryCreationThreshold)
        {
        }

        #endregion

        #region Overrides of KeyedCollection<string,LeaseInfo>

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override Guid GetKeyForItem(LeaseInfo item)
        {
            return item.LeaseId;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Hint: To use a custom object as a dictionary key based on its properties, you have to implement `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` on the custom object. Possible values for a hash code are between `int.MinValue` and `int.MaxValue`, so clearly collisions are possible.

Comment: It's just indexed retrieval is "by index" ( `myCollection[i]` ) and keyed is "by key" ( `myCollection[myKey]` ). Index refers to a specific _position_ in the collection, while the position of an element with a specific key could be anywhere in the collection, depending on how the datastructure handles keying. So you need to map key to position first, which has a (hopefully) small impact on time complexity.

Comment: @Fildor that makes sense - great

Comment: @John so if i get you right, i currently have MyCustomObject.Id as 'key' indexer for the keyedcollection. I should then also override gethashcode to use the guid so the dict indexes based on that - or am i wrong here? I'm now thinking that i do not need keyedcollection at all, i can just override gethashcode to use the guid and then use a dictionary instead - any advice?

Comment: Disregard that last comment - i was being dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is in the next paragraph of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.keyedcollection-2?view=netcore-3.1#remarks):

> The `KeyedCollection<TKey,TItem>` class is a hybrid between a collection
>   based on the `IList<T>` generic interface and a collection based on the
>   `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` generic interface. Like collections based on
>   the `IList<T>` generic interface, `KeyedCollection<TKey,TItem>` is an
>   indexed list of items. Like collections based on the
>   `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` generic interface,
>   `KeyedCollection<TKey,TItem>` has a key associated with each element.

From this paragraph we can learn that we can access elements of the `KeyedCollection` collection using their ordinal indexes or their keys.

Here is sample (based on the sample from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.keyedcollection-2?view=netcore-3.1#examples)) to show these two approaches to retrieve elements of `KeyedCollection`:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public OrderItem(string partNumber) => PartNumber = partNumber;

    public string PartNumber { get; }
}

// Custom KeyedCollection.
public class SimpleOrder : KeyedCollection<string, OrderItem>
{
    // Here we define how to get Key from Item for our custom KeyedCollection.
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(OrderItem item) => item.PartNumber;
}

internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        KeyedCollection<string, OrderItem> kc = new SimpleOrder();

        kc.Add(new OrderItem("#0"));
        kc.Add(new OrderItem("#1"));

        // Retrieve item by index.
        Console.WriteLine(kc[0].PartNumber);

        // Retrieve item by key.
        Console.WriteLine(kc["#1"].PartNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: I still was not clear about the text after, but when you string it together like this it makes sense - much obliged.